# Which code is right for Peterson's algorithm?

Tags: operating-system, interprocess

Recently I have started learning Inter process communication.
To implement peterson's algorithn I have found two codes:

1.#define N 2
 2. #define TRUE 1
 3. #define FALSE 0
 4. int INTERESTED[N] = FALSE
 5. int TURN;
 6. void Entry_Section(int process)
 7. {
 8. int other; 
 9. other = 1 – process;
 10. INTERESTED[process] = TRUE;
 11. TURN = process;
 12. while(INTERESTED[other] == TRUE && TURN = process)
 13. }
 14. void Exit_Section(int process)
 15. {
 16. INTERESTED[process] = FALSE;
 17. }

And

1.do
 2. { 
 3.flag[i]=True;
 4. turn=j;
 5. while (flag[j] && turn==j); // critical. 6.section flag[i]=False; // remainder. 7.section
 8. } while (True);

So I want to know which one is true.

I think the second one is correct.
Because:
(1st code)
When, context switch occurs after setting flag value 'turn = process' (process means its pointing itself) and next process comes in enter_regin() function. Both of the values of 'intrested[2]' array will be true. And the while loop after it (which acts as trap) will be true and non of the process can get out of it.

I just want to know am I right or wrong.